# Session timeout with azure Ad .net core 2.0

Tags: c#, azure, security, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I am trying to authenticate .net core 2.0 application with the Azure ad. I got it successful with authentication. But I need to session timeout after idle time.

Please find my startup.cs config

**Configure**

```
        logger.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        logger.AddDebug((category, logLevel) => (logLevel >= LogLevel.Trace));
        app.UseResponseCaching();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseBrowserLink();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseSession();
        app.UseAuthentication();
```

**ConfigureServices**

```
  services.AddAuthentication(options =>
             {
                 options.DefaultScheme= CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                 options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
             })
             .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
             {
                 options.ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:ClientId"];
                 options.Authority = Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:AADInstance"] + Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:TenantId"];
                 options.ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:ClientSecret"];
                 options.CallbackPath = Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:CallbackPath"];
                 options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken;
             })
             .AddCookie();

             services.AddSession(options =>
         {
             options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
             options.CookieHttpOnly = true;
         });
```

Answer (score 0):

As the section Implementation Details under [Working with Session State](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?tabs=aspnetcore2x#working-with-session-state) states as follows:

> The server uses the `IdleTimeout` property to determine how long a session can be idle before its contents are abandoned. **This property is independent of the cookie expiration. Each request that passes through the Session middleware (read from or written to) resets the timeout.**

I enabled the session state, then set session values in an action and read them in another action. Per my test, your configuration for `AddSession` would issue a cookie with the default name `.AspNetCore.Session` and contains the session ID to the browser. The IdleTimeout is 1 minute and if you read or update the session values, then the IdleTimeout would be reset.

**UPDATE:**

AFAIK, there is no SessionEvents under `SessionOptions` when using `services.AddSession`. Per my understanding, you could set the Cookie expire time when using cookie auth, then add the processing to remove the session values and send the sign-out request to AAD when the cookie is invalid. Here is my configuration, you could refer to it as follows:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add MVC services to the services container.
    services.AddMvc();

    // Add Authentication services.
    services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
    {
        sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })

        // Configure the OWIN pipeline to use OpenID Connect auth.
        .AddOpenIdConnect(option =>
        {
            option.ClientId = Configuration["AzureAD:ClientId"];
            option.Authority = String.Format(Configuration["AzureAd:AadInstance"], Configuration["AzureAd:Tenant"]);
            option.SignedOutRedirectUri = Configuration["AzureAd:PostLogoutRedirectUri"];
            option.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
            {
                OnRemoteFailure = OnAuthenticationFailed,
            };
        })// Configure the OWIN pipeline to use cookie auth.
        .AddCookie(op => {
            op.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
            op.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
            op.Events.OnRedirectToLogin =async(context) =>
                {   
                    //Clean the session values
                    context.HttpContext.Session.Clear();
                    //Sign-out to AAD
                    await context.HttpContext.SignOutAsync(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
                    //Redirect to op.LoginPath ("/Account/Login") for logging again
                    context.Response.Redirect(context.RedirectUri);
                };
        });

    services.AddSession(options =>
    {
        options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
        options.CookieHttpOnly = true;
    });
}
```

Comment: You are right. But i need to logout and redirect the page to login page after timeout. Could you please help me?

Comment: I updated my answer with some idea, you could refer to it.

Comment: I get Failed to load https://login.microsoftonline.com/7653af48-8d24-4c43-bbaa-b8547139c0f5/oauth2/authorize?ignin-0: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:12485' is therefore not allowed access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.