# Session Timeout redirect for Azure AD authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, session, azure-active-directory

I am using Azure AD for authentication in my Asp .Net Core 3.1 application.  I also need to handle session timeout for some session variables I'm setting.  I don't understand how to tie that together.  I created a filter action called SessionTimeout to annotate my controllers, but then I don't know where I should redirect based on lack of session.

Here's my Filter action:

```
public class SessionTimeout : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {

            if (filterContext.HttpContext.Session == null ||
                                !filterContext.HttpContext.Session.TryGetValue("UserId", out byte[] val))
            {
                filterContext.Result =
                    new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new
                    {
                        controller = "Home",
                        action = "Login"
                    }));
            }
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }
    
    }
```

but of course Home/Login doesn't exist when using AzureAD so I don't know where I should redirect.  And they're not necessarily needing to re-authenticate, just to re-establish the session variables so I'm not sure what I should be doing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to create `ActionFilter`.
[You can protect a controller or controller methods using the [Authorize] attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-aspnet-core-webapp#protect-a-controller-or-a-controllers-method).

And you can `services.AddSession` in your peoject. For more details, you can read [Session and state management in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

And I also found [a similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47035379/session-timeout-with-azure-ad-net-core-2-0), but it is based on .net core 2.0, but it should still be useful to you.

[image]

Comment: Okay but /Account/Login is not the login path for AzureAD login.  There's no local login.  I don't understand what to redirect to.  I already had the services.AddSession in my startup and it's not doing the trick.

Comment: @GeorgeHarris Are you still looking any on this question

Comment: @Thirgiftthub-MSFTIdentity yes I am.  Not sure what to do to handle session timeout with AzureAD login

Comment: If you found an answer to it?